# Keep Http session alive asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, session-timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping ASP.NET Session Open / Alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431733/keeping-asp-net-session-open-alive)
>   [What is the best approach to handle session timeouts in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308918/what-is-the-best-approach-to-handle-session-timeouts-in-asp-net)

Does anyone know how i can possibly keep an http session alive when the user still has the browser window  open?

Comment: also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642682/keeping-a-related-asp-net-applications-session-alive-from-another-asp-net-appli

Comment: Thank you. The above were very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

you can increase the sesion timeout in the iis settings

http://forums.asp.net/t/1283350.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/31a2f39c-4d59-4cba-905c-60e7af657e49.mspx?mfr=true