# How to keep session alive in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

Can anyone tell me how to keep alive session values in asp.net using C#. Session Values is going to expire within 1 minute during work also. anyone please help to keep my session values active during work to long time.

Comment: Try [googling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+to+keep+session+alive+in+asp.net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs&gfe_rd=cr&ei=eg4sVNLWLcPH8geSuYLoCg) your question title... how many results !!!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10550/The-Defibrillator-Keeping-ASP-NET-Session-Alive-Ad

Comment: You can also check this q/a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308918/what-is-the-best-approach-to-handle-session-timeouts-in-asp-net/3309046#3309046

Answer (score 1):

```
<system.web>

   <sessionState timeout="525600" mode="StateServer"/>

  </system.web>
```

put this in your webconfig...

Hope this help you...

Cheers!!